# Extendable apparatus

Tags: mechanical-engineering, statics

1. Is there a kind of "handbook" for general engineering ideas and possible applications?  I vaguely remember a machinist friend mentioning some standard book to glean ideas from...
2. I'm in need of an extendable arm.  I wish to raise something into the air ~10-12 feet (with no anchor above), hold ~3-5 lbs, and be as compact as possible when retracted.  Telescoping mechanisms are the obvious choice, but I think their collapsed size makes them already too long (especially to reach 12 feet, with their sections being >2 feet).  I'd like to be able to carry this on a belt or small harness without being cumbersome.

My mind keeps turning to something like a retractable tape measure but I'm sure there's a better solution, and that's not stable enough to hold the weight steady.

Thanks in advance, I appreciate you reading this!

Answer (score 1):

For mechanical devices, a good source of information is "Mechanisms and Mechanical Devices Sourcebook" by Sclater and Chironis (McGraw-Hill, 2007).

Another good book is "507 Mechanical Movements - Mechanisms and Devices" by Brown.

A google search on "mechanisms" and "machine design" will throw up a lot of possibilities.  Beyond that, a patent search is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

the handboook is probably the *McMaster-Carr Company* parts catalog, which contains all sorts of mechanical gizmos and doodads available off-the-shelf for jobs like yours.

Comment: Thanks for your input!  I've been using McMaster to fuel most of my projects so I'm no stranger to them :-)  I seem to remember a mention of some "standard designs" type of thing... have XX requirement, proposed YY and ZZ standard application of pulleys/levers/cogs/whatever.  Maybe I'm totally mis-remembering it!

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is impractical and impossible to handle even in a scale that a normal person wrist can handle.

Basically anything that can deploy a load of 5lbs at a distance of 12 feet, if it has a handle that you describe in the order of 6 inches, will cause a torque of $$5*12ft/0.5ft=120lbs.ft\ $$  Which is beyond a regular man wrist power.

Comment: Thanks for your input!  Perhaps my 3-5lb weight was a bit overestimated and half that might be more reasonable.  I'd like to clarify that I'm mainly interested in lifting the load straight up.  

I made a test rig using a tape measure as a proof of concept and it did indeed support a ~1.5lb load straight up, but the second it swayed left or right the rig buckled and the tape collapsed.

Comment: Some serious unit problems with this math.

Comment: @Sebastian  The "tape measure" method is used for some ultra-compact and light applications, such as the mars rover. You might try using 2 large tape measures back to back?, or 3? If you combine 2 standard telescoping poles you can probably get 10 ft with decent rigidity,

Comment: I think it was the viking lander that used this mechanism: https://www.google.com/search?q=viking+lander+furlable+arm&tbm=isch